# What is the best way to save an image sequence with different time intervals in a simgle file in C++

Tags: c++, image-processing, timestamp, storage

in my system, I have a camera, and I have got an image sequence from the camera, but the time interval between each image is not the same. See below:

```
 ┌─────┐  ┌─────┐  ┌─────┐  ┌─────┐
 │     │  │     │  │     │  │     │
 │image├─►│image├─►│image├─►│image├─►
 │     │  │     │  │     │  │     │
 └─────┘  └─────┘  └─────┘  └─────┘
   t0       t1       t2       t3
```

Basically, `t1-t0 != t2-t1`, and `t3-t2 != t2-t1`.

A simple method could same those images as separate files, such as `09-39-001.png`, `09-39-058.png`, the file name contains the minute-second-millisecond timestamp of the image. With this method, I got a lot of files, and it runs slowly if I got a lot of images. The reason I guess is that there are two many file creation option to the disk.

I know there are a lot of method to store them in a single file, for example, save them to a `mp4` file, e.g. the `OpenCV` library has a way to write to a `mp4` file by `cv::VideoWriter` object. But with this method, the `mp4` file stores images in a const rate(such as 30fps), and my time stamp information is lost. When I try to replay the mp4 file, each image(frame) is played in a const time interval way. The only good thing is the mp4 is compressed thus its file size is smaller than the total amount of separate image files.

I heard that the `ROS` system can capture and save images in a `bag` or `bag2` file, and I think using `ROS` is a bit complex for my simple project. In my simple project, I need to capture camera images and one or more sensor data from other sources, so I do need a way to save those data so that I can reply them later precisely in time.

As a conclusion, I need a method to same data with their time stamp in a simple file, and later playback again. Hopefully the file could be compressed like the `mp4` file, but I think file size is the secondary factor.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253380/discussion-on-question-by-ollydbg23-what-is-the-best-way-to-save-an-image-sequen); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can answer this question myself, there are several ways to handle this:

**Method 1, using the `FFmpeg` library(which supports variable frame rate recording)**

This is done in my answer to my own question here: [save a serial of images(cv::Mat) to a mp4 file in Variable Frame Rate mode by using `ffmpeg` library, how to set the pts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76146859/save-a-serial-of-imagescvmat-to-a-mp4-file-in-variable-frame-rate-mode-by-us)

In this answer(with source code), I can correctly set the `PTS` value of each frame, and the result mp4 file will respect each time stamp of the image.

source code:

save to mp4 file: [opencv-image-to-mp4.cpp](https://gist.github.com/asmwarrior/701bdd914c53d6853beb6e50dd99c6f5)

read mp4 file and show them by opencv: [read_image_from_mp4_imshow.cpp](https://gist.github.com/asmwarrior/dc0cbaf37d69eb0561adad1e364a7d5d)

**Method 2, using the original `OpenCV` method `cv::VideoWriter`, which only support constant frame rate recording, but time stamp can be saved in another file**

With this method, I have to add a separate file, such as "timestamp.txt" file along with the mp4 file, this file should contains the timestamp of each saved image in the video file, as in the discussion suggest by @fana, I have a test code in github gist: [save image sequence to mp4 file, and read them back](https://gist.github.com/asmwarrior/f60c891e76361091f509db1f65c9ddff)