# using ffmpeg libraray to write to a mp4, ffprobe shows there are 100 frames and 100 packets, but av_interleaved_write_frame only called 50 times

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

here is my code to generate a mp4 file by using ffmpeg and opencv library. The opencv library is only try to generate 100 images(frames), and ffmpeg library is to compress the images to a mp4 files.

Here is the working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
extern "C" {
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
}

#include<cstdlib> // to generate time stamps

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Set up input frames as BGR byte arrays
    vector<Mat> frames;

    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;
    int num_frames = 100;
    Scalar black(0, 0, 0);
    Scalar white(255, 255, 255);
    int font = FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX;
    double font_scale = 1.0;
    int thickness = 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_frames; i++) {
        Mat frame = Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_8UC3);
        putText(frame, std::to_string(i), Point(width / 2 - 50, height / 2), font, font_scale, white, thickness);
        frames.push_back(frame);
    }

    // generate a serial of time stamps which is used to set the PTS value
    // suppose they are in ms unit, the time interval is between 30ms to 59ms
    vector<int> timestamps;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_frames; i++) {
        int timestamp;
        if (i == 0)
            timestamp = 0;
        else
        {
            int random = 30 + (rand() % 30);
            timestamp = timestamps[i-0] + random;
        }

        timestamps.push_back(timestamp);
    }

    // Populate frames with BGR byte arrays

    // Initialize FFmpeg
    //av_register_all();

    // Set up output file
    AVFormatContext* outFormatCtx = nullptr;
    //AVCodec* outCodec = nullptr;
    AVCodecContext* outCodecCtx = nullptr;
    //AVStream* outStream = nullptr;
    //AVPacket outPacket;

    const char* outFile = "output.mp4";
    int outWidth = frames[0].cols;
    int outHeight = frames[0].rows;
    int fps = 25;

    // Open the output file context
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&outFormatCtx, nullptr, nullptr, outFile);
    if (!outFormatCtx) {
        cerr << "Error: Could not allocate output format context" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Open the output file
    if (avio_open(&outFormatCtx->pb, outFile, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE) < 0) {
        cerr << "Error opening output file" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Set up output codec
    const AVCodec* outCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    if (!outCodec) {
        cerr << "Error: Could not find H.264 codec" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    outCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(outCodec);
    if (!outCodecCtx) {
        cerr << "Error: Could not allocate output codec context" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    outCodecCtx->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
    outCodecCtx->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    outCodecCtx->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    outCodecCtx->width = outWidth;
    outCodecCtx->height = outHeight;
    //outCodecCtx->time_base = { 1, fps*1000 };   // 25000
    outCodecCtx->time_base = { 1, fps};   // 25000
    outCodecCtx->framerate = {fps, 1};          // 25
    outCodecCtx->bit_rate = 4000000;

    //https://github.com/leandromoreira/ffmpeg-libav-tutorial
    //We set the flag AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER which tells the encoder that it can use the global headers.
    if (outFormatCtx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
    {
        outCodecCtx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER; //
    }

    // Open output codec
    if (avcodec_open2(outCodecCtx, outCodec, nullptr) < 0) {
        cerr << "Error: Could not open output codec" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Create output stream
    AVStream* outStream = avformat_new_stream(outFormatCtx, outCodec);
    if (!outStream) {
        cerr << "Error: Could not allocate output stream" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Configure output stream parameters (e.g., time base, codec parameters, etc.)
    // ...

    // Connect output stream to format context
    outStream->codecpar->codec_id = outCodecCtx->codec_id;
    outStream->codecpar->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    outStream->codecpar->width = outCodecCtx->width;
    outStream->codecpar->height = outCodecCtx->height;
    outStream->codecpar->format = outCodecCtx->pix_fmt;
    outStream->time_base = outCodecCtx->time_base;

    int ret = avcodec_parameters_from_context(outStream->codecpar, outCodecCtx);
    if (ret < 0) {
        cerr << "Error: Could not copy codec parameters to output stream" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    outStream->avg_frame_rate = outCodecCtx->framerate;
    //outStream->id = outFormatCtx->nb_streams++;  <--- We shouldn't modify outStream->id

    ret = avformat_write_header(outFormatCtx, nullptr);
    if (ret < 0) {
        cerr << "Error: Could not write output header" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Convert frames to YUV format and write to output file
    int frame_count = -1;
    for (const auto& frame : frames) {
        frame_count++;
        AVFrame* yuvFrame = av_frame_alloc();
        if (!yuvFrame) {
            cerr << "Error: Could not allocate YUV frame" << endl;
            return -1;
        }
        av_image_alloc(yuvFrame->data, yuvFrame->linesize, outWidth, outHeight, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, 32);

        yuvFrame->width = outWidth;
        yuvFrame->height = outHeight;
        yuvFrame->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

        // Convert BGR frame to YUV format
        Mat yuvMat;
        cvtColor(frame, yuvMat, COLOR_BGR2YUV_I420);
        memcpy(yuvFrame->data[0], yuvMat.data, outWidth * outHeight);
        memcpy(yuvFrame->data[1], yuvMat.data + outWidth * outHeight, outWidth * outHeight / 4);
        memcpy(yuvFrame->data[2], yuvMat.data + outWidth * outHeight * 5 / 4, outWidth * outHeight / 4);

        // Set up output packet
        //av_init_packet(&outPacket); //error C4996: 'av_init_packet': was declared deprecated
        AVPacket* outPacket = av_packet_alloc();
        memset(outPacket, 0, sizeof(outPacket)); //Use memset instead of av_init_packet (probably unnecessary).
        //outPacket->data = nullptr;
        //outPacket->size = 0;

        // set the frame pts, do I have to set the package pts?

        // yuvFrame->pts = av_rescale_q(timestamps[frame_count]*25, outCodecCtx->time_base, outStream->time_base); //Set PTS timestamp
        yuvFrame->pts = av_rescale_q(frame_count*frame_count, outCodecCtx->time_base, outStream->time_base); //Set PTS timestamp

        // Encode frame and write to output file
        int ret = avcodec_send_frame(outCodecCtx, yuvFrame);
        if (ret < 0) {
            cerr << "Error: Could not send frame to output codec" << endl;
            return -1;
        }
        while (ret >= 0)
        {
            ret = avcodec_receive_packet(outCodecCtx, outPacket);

            if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
            {
                int abc;
                abc++;
                break;
            }
            else if (ret < 0)
            {
                cerr << "Error: Could not receive packet from output codec" << endl;
                return -1;
            }

            //av_packet_rescale_ts(&outPacket, outCodecCtx->time_base, outStream->time_base);

            outPacket->stream_index = outStream->index;

            outPacket->duration = av_rescale_q(1, outCodecCtx->time_base, outStream->time_base);   // Set packet duration

            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(outFormatCtx, outPacket);

            static int call_write = 0;

            call_write++;
            printf("av_interleaved_write_frame %d\n", call_write);

            av_packet_unref(outPacket);
            if (ret < 0) {
                cerr << "Error: Could not write packet to output file" << endl;
                return -1;
            }
        }

        av_frame_free(&yuvFrame);
    }

    // Flush the encoder
    ret = avcodec_send_frame(outCodecCtx, nullptr);
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error flushing encoder: " << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    while (ret >= 0) {
        AVPacket* pkt = av_packet_alloc();
        if (!pkt) {
            std::cerr << "Error allocating packet" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(outCodecCtx, pkt);

        // Write the packet to the output file
        if (ret == 0)
        {
            pkt->stream_index = outStream->index;
            pkt->duration = av_rescale_q(1, outCodecCtx->time_base, outStream->time_base);   // <---- Set packet duration
            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(outFormatCtx, pkt);
            av_packet_unref(pkt);
            if (ret < 0) {
                std::cerr << "Error writing packet to output file: " << std::endl;
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }


    // Write output trailer
    av_write_trailer(outFormatCtx);

    // Clean up
    avcodec_close(outCodecCtx);
    avcodec_free_context(&outCodecCtx);
    avformat_free_context(outFormatCtx);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I have used the `ffprobe` tool(one of the tool from ffmpeg) to inspect the generated mp4 files.

I see that the mp4 file has 100 frames and 100 packets, but in my code, I have such lines:

```
            static int call_write = 0;

            call_write++;
            printf("av_interleaved_write_frame %d\n", call_write);
```

I just see that the `av_interleaved_write_frame` function is only called 50 times, not the expected 100 times, anyone can explain it?

Thanks.

BTW, from the ffmpeg document( see here: [For video, it should typically contain one compressed frame](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVPacket.html#details) ), I see that a `packet` mainly has one video `frame`, so the `ffprobe`'s result looks correct.

Here is the command I used to inspect the mp4 file:

```
ffprobe -show_frames output.mp4 >> frames.txt
ffprobe -show_packets output.mp4 >> packets.txt
```

My testing code is derived from an answer in another question here: [avformat_write_header() function call crashed when I try to save several RGB data to a output.mp4 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76141344/avformat-write-header-function-call-crashed-when-i-try-to-save-several-rgb-dat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the reason:

In the code:

```
    for (const auto& frame : frames) {
```

I do see there are 100 frame get encoded, and I see the `av_interleaved_write_frame` function is called 50 time, while, after this for loop, there is another loop.

```
while (ret >= 0) {
```

I see there are extra 50 function calls of `av_interleaved_write_frame`. So, the total function call is 100 times, and the total frames/packets were 100 in the final mp4 file.