# save a serial of images(cv::Mat) to a mp4 file in Variable Frame Rate mode by using ffmpeg library, how to set the pts?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

In C++ code, I can correctly save a serial of images(opencv's `cv::Mat`) to a mp4 file by using `ffmpeg` library, see the question and answer here: [avformat_write_header() function call crashed when I try to save several RGB data to a output.mp4 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76141344/avformat-write-header-function-call-crashed-when-i-try-to-save-several-rgb-dat)

Now here comes another question:

Rotem' answer in that question can have the `output.mp4` saved correctly. When play the mp4 file, I see the frames(OpenCV's `cv::Mat` image) shows in a const rate.

What I can do if I have got the frames not in a const frequency, for example, the I got the first frame at the `0ms`, and the second frame at the `50ms` the third frame at `75ms`, so that the each frame as associated time stamp, for example, those time stamp array are something like below:

```
int timestamp[100] = {0, 50, 75, ...};
```

What is the method to modify the Rotem's answer to reflect this? It looks like I have to change the `pts` field of each `frame`. Because I just test the code, if I change this:

```
yuvFrame->pts = av_rescale_q(frame_count*frame_count, outCodecCtx->time_base, outStream->time_base); //Set PTS timestamp

// note I change from frame_count to frame_count*frame_count
```

Then the `output.mp4` plays slower and slower, because the later frame has large `pts` values.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

This is the code I'm currently used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
extern "C" {
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
}

#include<cstdlib> // to generate time stamps

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Set up input frames as BGR byte arrays
    vector<Mat> frames;

    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;
    int num_frames = 100;
    Scalar black(0, 0, 0);
    Scalar white(255, 255, 255);
    int font = FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX;
    double font_scale = 1.0;
    int thickness = 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_frames; i++) {
        Mat frame = Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_8UC3);
        putText(frame, std::to_string(i), Point(width / 2 - 50, height / 2), font, font_scale, white, thickness);
        frames.push_back(frame);
    }

    // generate a serial of time stamps which is used to set the PTS value
    // suppose they are in ms unit, the time interval is between 30ms to 59ms
    vector<int> timestamps;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_frames; i++) {
        int timestamp;
        if (i == 0)
            timestamp = 0;
        else
        {
            int random = 30 + (rand() % 30);
            timestamp = timestamps[i-0] + random;
        }

        timestamps.push_back(timestamp);
    }

    // Populate frames with BGR byte arrays

    // Initialize FFmpeg
    //av_register_all();

    // Set up output file
    AVFormatContext* outFormatCtx = nullptr;
    //AVCodec* outCodec = nullptr;
    AVCodecContext* outCodecCtx = nullptr;
    //AVStream* outStream = nullptr;
    //AVPacket outPacket;

    const char* outFile = "output.mp4";
    int outWidth = frames[0].cols;
    int outHeight = frames[0].rows;
    int fps = 25;

    // Open the output file context
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&outFormatCtx, nullptr, nullptr, outFile);
    if (!outFormatCtx) {
        cerr << "Error: Could not allocate output format context" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Open the output file
    if (avio_open(&outFormatCtx->pb, outFile, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE) < 0) {
        cerr << "Error opening output file" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Set up output codec
    const AVCodec* outCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    if (!outCodec) {
        cerr << "Error: Could not find H.264 codec" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    outCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(outCodec);
    if (!outCodecCtx) {
        cerr << "Error: Could not allocate output codec context" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    outCodecCtx->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
    outCodecCtx->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    outCodecCtx->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    outCodecCtx->width = outWidth;
    outCodecCtx->height = outHeight;
    outCodecCtx->time_base = { 1, fps*1000 };   // 25000
    outCodecCtx->framerate = {fps, 1};          // 25
    outCodecCtx->bit_rate = 4000000;

    //https://github.com/leandromoreira/ffmpeg-libav-tutorial
    //We set the flag AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER which tells the encoder that it can use the global headers.
    if (outFormatCtx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
    {
        outCodecCtx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER; //
    }

    // Open output codec
    if (avcodec_open2(outCodecCtx, outCodec, nullptr) < 0) {
        cerr << "Error: Could not open output codec" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Create output stream
    AVStream* outStream = avformat_new_stream(outFormatCtx, outCodec);
    if (!outStream) {
        cerr << "Error: Could not allocate output stream" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Configure output stream parameters (e.g., time base, codec parameters, etc.)
    // ...

    // Connect output stream to format context
    outStream->codecpar->codec_id = outCodecCtx->codec_id;
    outStream->codecpar->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    outStream->codecpar->width = outCodecCtx->width;
    outStream->codecpar->height = outCodecCtx->height;
    outStream->codecpar->format = outCodecCtx->pix_fmt;
    outStream->time_base = outCodecCtx->time_base;

    int ret = avcodec_parameters_from_context(outStream->codecpar, outCodecCtx);
    if (ret < 0) {
        cerr << "Error: Could not copy codec parameters to output stream" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    outStream->avg_frame_rate = outCodecCtx->framerate;
    //outStream->id = outFormatCtx->nb_streams++;  <--- We shouldn't modify outStream->id

    ret = avformat_write_header(outFormatCtx, nullptr);
    if (ret < 0) {
        cerr << "Error: Could not write output header" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Convert frames to YUV format and write to output file
    int frame_count = -1;
    for (const auto& frame : frames) {
        frame_count++;
        AVFrame* yuvFrame = av_frame_alloc();
        if (!yuvFrame) {
            cerr << "Error: Could not allocate YUV frame" << endl;
            return -1;
        }
        av_image_alloc(yuvFrame->data, yuvFrame->linesize, outWidth, outHeight, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, 32);

        yuvFrame->width = outWidth;
        yuvFrame->height = outHeight;
        yuvFrame->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

        // Convert BGR frame to YUV format
        Mat yuvMat;
        cvtColor(frame, yuvMat, COLOR_BGR2YUV_I420);
        memcpy(yuvFrame->data[0], yuvMat.data, outWidth * outHeight);
        memcpy(yuvFrame->data[1], yuvMat.data + outWidth * outHeight, outWidth * outHeight / 4);
        memcpy(yuvFrame->data[2], yuvMat.data + outWidth * outHeight * 5 / 4, outWidth * outHeight / 4);

        // Set up output packet
        //av_init_packet(&outPacket); //error C4996: 'av_init_packet': was declared deprecated
        AVPacket* outPacket = av_packet_alloc();
        memset(outPacket, 0, sizeof(outPacket)); //Use memset instead of av_init_packet (probably unnecessary).
        //outPacket->data = nullptr;
        //outPacket->size = 0;

        yuvFrame->pts = av_rescale_q(timestamps[frame_count], outCodecCtx->time_base, outStream->time_base); //Set PTS timestamp

        // Encode frame and write to output file
        int ret = avcodec_send_frame(outCodecCtx, yuvFrame);
        if (ret < 0) {
            cerr << "Error: Could not send frame to output codec" << endl;
            return -1;
        }
        while (ret >= 0) {
            ret = avcodec_receive_packet(outCodecCtx, outPacket);
            if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
                break;
            } else if (ret < 0) {
                cerr << "Error: Could not receive packet from output codec" << endl;
                return -1;
            }

            //av_packet_rescale_ts(&outPacket, outCodecCtx->time_base, outStream->time_base);

            outPacket->stream_index = outStream->index;

            outPacket->duration = av_rescale_q(1, outCodecCtx->time_base, outStream->time_base);   // Set packet duration

            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(outFormatCtx, outPacket);
            av_packet_unref(outPacket);
            if (ret < 0) {
                cerr << "Error: Could not write packet to output file" << endl;
                return -1;
            }
        }

        av_frame_free(&yuvFrame);
    }

    // Flush the encoder
    ret = avcodec_send_frame(outCodecCtx, nullptr);
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error flushing encoder: " << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    while (ret >= 0) {
        AVPacket* pkt = av_packet_alloc();
        if (!pkt) {
            std::cerr << "Error allocating packet" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(outCodecCtx, pkt);

        // Write the packet to the output file
        if (ret == 0)
        {
            pkt->stream_index = outStream->index;
            pkt->duration = av_rescale_q(1, outCodecCtx->time_base, outStream->time_base);   // <---- Set packet duration
            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(outFormatCtx, pkt);
            av_packet_unref(pkt);
            if (ret < 0) {
                std::cerr << "Error writing packet to output file: " << std::endl;
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }


    // Write output trailer
    av_write_trailer(outFormatCtx);

    // Clean up
    avcodec_close(outCodecCtx);
    avcodec_free_context(&outCodecCtx);
    avformat_free_context(outFormatCtx);

    return 0;
}
```

Especially, I have those changes to the original Rotem's answer:

Fist, I have some code to generate a time stamp array:

```
    // generate a serial of time stamps which is used to set the PTS value
    // suppose they are in ms unit, the time interval is between 30ms to 59ms
    vector<int> timestamps;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_frames; i++) {
        int timestamp;
        if (i == 0)
            timestamp = 0;
        else
        {
            int random = 30 + (rand() % 30);
            timestamp = timestamps[i-0] + random;
        }

        timestamps.push_back(timestamp);
    }
```

Second, I just set the PTS by those values:

```
        yuvFrame->pts = av_rescale_q(timestamps[frame_count], outCodecCtx->time_base, outStream->time_base); //Set PTS timestamp
```

Note that I have set the fps like below:

```
    outCodecCtx->time_base = { 1, fps*1000 };   // 25000
    outCodecCtx->framerate = {fps, 1};          // 25
```

Now, when I run the program, I got a lot of warnings in the console:

```
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] profile High, level 3.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] 264 - core 164 r3094M bfc87b7 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2022 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=4000 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] non-strictly-monotonic PTS
[libx264 @ 0000022e7fa621c0] invalid DTS: PTS is less than DTS
[mp4 @ 0000022e090b2300] pts (592) < dts (1129348497) in stream 0
Error: Could not write packet to output file
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the answer, there is a bug in my code:

```
    // generate a serial of time stamps which is used to set the PTS value
    // suppose they are in ms unit, the time interval is between 30ms to 59ms
    vector<int> timestamps;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_frames; i++) {
        int timestamp;
        if (i == 0)
            timestamp = 0;
        else
        {
            int random = 30 + (rand() % 30);
            timestamp = timestamps[i-0] + random;
        }

        timestamps.push_back(timestamp);
    }
```

Here, the bug is the `timestamps[i-0]`, it should be `timestamps[i-1]`, with such changes, I can get a correctly monotonically increasing array of timestamps, and I don't have the `non-strictly-monotonic PTS` like issue now when running the fixed code.

This discussion gives me many help: [Discussion between ollydbg23 and Rotem | chat.stackoverflow.com](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253423/discussion-between-ollydbg23-and-rotem)

Especially the sentence:

> When encoding, we set the PTS of the frame. The PTS and DTS of the
> packets are filled automatically (from the frame PTS). All you have to
> do is pts = pts_list[frame_count] and scale the pts according to the
> timebase of the stream.

So, many thanks to @[Rotem](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/4926757/rotem).

I have post the final working code here in github gist:

[opencv-image-to-mp4.cpp](https://gist.github.com/asmwarrior/701bdd914c53d6853beb6e50dd99c6f5)